# Updating the view of a screen in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Hey—I’m working on an angular 1.6 app, and I’ve come across an issue I’m not quite sure how to resolve. Here’s a brief discussion of the set up. The page is a form with thirty questions. There is a lot of conditional logic from the client that goes as follows: if user selects “Yes” on Q1 then show them Q2-4, if “No” on Q1, then skip to Q5. This repeats itself in the thirty question form.

I’ve come across the following scenario—what if the user selects “Yes” on Q1, answers Q2-4 and then realizes Q1 should really be “No”.

So my question is: 1) how do I clear the models? and 2) how do I update the view? So that if they decide, third time around, that Q1 should in fact be yes, Q2-Q4 are unchecked/clear/blank.

For 1) I just wrote a simple “clearAll method as follows:

```
function clearAll(arr){
        arr.forEach(function(element){
            if(element!==undefined){
                 element = null; 
            }    
        });
    }
```

This clears the models but doesn’t update the view. How do I update the view so that Q2-4 are clear/empty/blank?

The idea I had is to update the view, so

```
$scope.$watch( myModel, function(val){
    //set to null or delete?
}
```

But I cannot generalize this so it is flexible enough to accept an array. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Assign the function to `$scope.` then it will trigger change detection, or call `$scope.apply()`

Comment: We're using "controller as" syntax so I'd prefer to avoid scope. Even if I want to use $scope.$apply() it throws errors related to the digest cycle.

Comment: Also, rather than clearing, decide what to save on server side or during sending, based on condition, therefor you won't have any of this problems.

Comment: Angular is build around scope. Post part of your controller to let me see what is going on. And if it throws, than it is updating... then you probably should look for error somewhere else

Comment: Yeah, the models are being updated (and I can check in chrome dev tools to verify), but the view is not. I want to trigger/force a change in the view.

Comment: You could wrap your $scope.$apply() in $timeout function if you have problems with that.

Comment: And if you call apply afterwards? Will it properly update? If not it seems as if the array is not linked to scope properly.

Comment: Your `clearAll` function does not "clear models". It doesn't do anything, really. `element = null` just sets the local variable, not the array value, to null. You'd need to do something more along the lines of `$scope.arrayOfModels = []`.

Comment: @noppa: ouch. you are right. $scope.$watch it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular problem I would use ui-router and resolve different states based on a question, i.e. `state.questions` and take different parameters like if you have url `/questions` as your base intro page (maybe weclome to questions or something), you would have `/questions/1` and it would be 1st question `/questions/2` would be second etc...
Then keep one list of objects on some simple service i.e.:

```
let questions = [];
```

which will persist throughout the app, later to be filled with some objects like:

```
{ 
q1: {
  answers: [1,2,3]
},
{
q2: {
  answers: [1,3]
}
```

You can always clear it after you are done with it or push new answer. Also you can check for particular answer before even loading the state, and this will give you great flexibility what you actually want.

well for ugly solution your watch maybe could work if you add watch group and timeout:

```
$scope.$watchGroup(arrayOfModels, (newVal, oldVal)=>{
  if(newVal) {
   // now do something you want with that models
   // if they don't apply, try $timeout(()=> $scope.$apply());
  }
})
```

Comment: Ah thank you, but I'm just building on some existing legacy code so I just need to fix the existing issues for production. :-/

Comment: It's never too late to do it properly :) Fixing issues with some workarounds just digs a deeper hole. If you want different help you can post some of your code and we can try to help with that.

Comment: There isn't a lot of code in the controller. Just an init, save and clearAll, but I agree w/ your comments. It's monkey patching.I suspect the correct approach (given my time constraints) might be to do the briefly discussed 2nd approach: $scope.$watch(arrayOfModels, function(){//delete appropriate models }); Or something similar.

Comment: I added some additional code in answer that you may want to check, and I see noppa has some useful comment on your clear function